# Labels based on other columns in Power BI

Tags: graph, powerbi, label, categorical

I have a problem regarding labels in Power BI.

My data looks like this. I have a table and want to filter it on English or France, based on the current user.

[Table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isJMN.png)

If I choose company E, I only want to show the three labels "started", "not started" and "finished". If I choose company F, I only want to show the three analogous labels in French. Right now, all six labels of Status show up when using the column as value.

Is there any way this is doable? I'd prefer not to split up my data into to different tables, since new data keeps coming into my database.

Best,
Erik

Comment: I can't see any problem here. What do you mean with "using the column as value"?

Comment: Hi Peter and thank you for your answer. The problem is that i show all six values in the legend, where I would like to show only the three one that are in the same language as the company of choice. For example, if I filter on an English company, I want to show the legend only in English and vice versa. By "using the column as  value", I mean that the column of Status in entered as the measure on the Y-axis.